# How to calculate (x,y,z) from (0,0,0) having a distance ,say, r?

Tags: geometry, circles

How can I determine the **3D** coordinates (x,y,z) from a given distance **r** with origin at **(0,0,0)**.

I know that in case of **2D (x,y)**,
 **x = r.sin(theta)** and
**y = r.cos(theta)**,
where **theta** is angle in degrees.

Do we have a similar formula for the **3D** case?

Comment: Look it up here: [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system)

Comment: @AsafHaas link is broken

Comment: @nashynash: no, it's not. Wikipedia.

Comment: ok. Now it shows correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system):
\begin{align}
x&=r\sin\phi\cos\theta\\
y&=r\sin\phi\sin\theta\\
z&=r\cos\phi\\
\end{align}
$\phi$ and $\theta$ are the equivalent of latitude and longitude.

Comment: Is θ between [0,360]. If so what about ϕ?

Comment: $0\le\phi\le\pi$, $0\le\theta\le2\,\pi$ (in radians.)

Comment: Thank you very much. You answer works perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

The $\theta$-thing is called "parameterization". Because the distance between $(x,y)$ and $(0,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ (think of this as your "2D") is defined as $\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$, so you saw that we can write $(x,y)$ using only one parameter, $\theta$, given the distance, $r$. In the same token, since in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ (think of this as your "3D") the distance between $(x,y,z)$ and $(0,0,0)$ is defined as $\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}$, we can use what is called "spherical parameterization" to write $(x,y,z)$ in another form. In case you just want to know the intuition behind this this: note that $r = \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}$ is equivalent to $r^{2} = x^{2} + y^{2}$ (does this remind you of a circle of center $(0,0)$ and radius $r$? It should!);  note that $r = \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}$ is equivalent to $r^{2} = x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}$, which is the Cartesian equation for a sphere of center $(0,0,0)$ and radius $r$ in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Comment: Thank you. But @Julian answer is what I am looking for.

Comment: @nashynash, no problem no worries. You can still "make it up" by upvoting :D

Comment: I tried that already but I need 2 more points to do that :(

Answer (score 0):

Besides spherical coordinates, you can work by normalizing an arbitrary vector.

In 2D,

$$r\frac{\vec v}{\|\vec v\|}=\left(r\frac{v_x}{\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}},r\frac{v_y}{\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}}\right),$$

and in 3D...

$$r\frac{\vec v}{\|\vec v\|}=\left(r\frac{v_x}{\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2}},r\frac{v_y}{\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2}},r\frac{v_z}{\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2}}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you. But @Julian answer is what I am looking for.